# Why would a plane opt out of flying through a class bravo?

Tags: air-traffic-control, airport

High performance planes that depart Chicago Executive are always vectored to the left of departing towards O'Hare airspace. They than loop around the airport until above O'Hare airspace and continue with their flight. Here is a picture of one example.
[image]

[image]

Why wouldn't they just fly through the airspace?

Comment: Are you asking why ATC vectors aircraft away from O'Hare airspace or why pilots "opt out" of flying through that airspace?

Comment: As a Low Hour Private Pilot, some Bravos are WAY more busy and complex than others.  I'll avoid the Dallas Class B if at all possible, but am comfortable inside other ones (MCI, SEA).  That is a Pilot Choice.  But in your scenario, it looks like its probably an ATC choice.

Comment: The better title for the question might be, *"Why don't controllers vector aircraft through the Class Bravo?"* since, flying IFR, where the vectors take you is the controller's call, not the pilot's (within reason... you don't have to take a vector into the middle of the thunderstorm, for instance).

Comment: To pile on, the premise of your question is incorrect. Whether flying IFR or VFR, all operations in Class B airspace are subject to an ATC clearance. The pilots are not "opting out" of flying through the Bravo; they are complying with ATC, and ATC does not want them flying through the Bravo.

Comment: @abelenky I also notice that students at many flight schools also avoid Class B airspace for some particular reason. It even goes up to the commercial applicant level and it is pretty funny to me. I see so many XC flight plans where the route goes in a mile wide gap between a restricted and a class B. It is kind of funny in my opinion.

Comment: @SMSvonderTann Students aren't allowed into class B as I understand stand from federal aviation regulations.

Comment: @Boeing787: Students aren't allowed in B *until signed off by instructor*. And certainly any commercial applicant should already lower-level certs and be Bravo-approved.  My only point is that some recreational/hobbyist pilots who are technically allowed in B might want to avoid it anyway, because it can be a challenging space.

Comment: The class B airspace begins at 3000 ft. msl above Chicago Executive. So, in your example, the Netjet airplane, whether or not it is arriving or departing (and at some point passing directly overhead of O'Hare) is operating in class B airspace during a portion of its flight.

Comment: @757toga I see, the plane was departing from Chicago Executive.

Comment: @abelenky Student pilots, even with a class B CFI sign off, cannot take off or land at any one of several airports located in Class B airspace. Chicago O'Hare, for example.

Comment: @Boeing787 I am more of referring to pilots who are full-time students getting instruction from a flight school. A lot of them already have their private, commercial with instrument ratings and are still afraid of getting in or near a Class B airspace even though they are legally allowed to. I notice this more in 141 or high-traffic 61 schools where students there get very little flight experience outside of their training.

Comment: @Boeing787 What altitudes do the different colors correspond to? Class B extends up to 10000 ft, so it's possible they are still flying through the Bravo airspace.

Comment: @mmathis The plane was at 17000 when they were passing over O'Hare airspace.

Comment: I've added another flight path with the same intent of waiting untill above O'Hare airspace.

Comment: The flight path you are showing in the new image does take the aircraft into the Class B airspace (unless it is flying extremely low, below 1900 ft), which is unlikely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your question refers to "high performance" aircraft (NETJETS is depicted in your example). So, I'm assuming that this high performance aircraft, shown in your first example, is operating IFR and is passing over O'Hare enroute to/from Chicago Executive Airport.

The class B airspace begins at 3000 ft. msl above Chicago Executive. So, in your example, the Netjet airplane, whether or not it is arriving or departing (and at some point passing directly overhead of O'Hare) is operating in class B airspace during a portion of its flight.

From my experience, it's not uncommon that ATC's local procedures route aircraft directly over a major airport (like O'Hare) enroute to/from satellite airports (as in the example in your question).

This type of structured and internally standardized routing, with appropriate assigned altitudes, can keep the aircraft away from the primary arrival and departure corridors of the major airport, which helps in reducing the complexity of providing separation from crossing traffic.

Even for light general aviation (VFR or IFR) traffic the procedures - routing directly over the major airport - (not necessarily using the same altitudes) could be the same as for high performance aircraft.

Comment: But the main question was "Why wouldn't they just fly through the airspace?". I undestood that why they have to first do this spiral and not just being vectored above that airport straight away. (You do not have to explain the reasons to me, but I think that was what was asked.).

Answer (score 1):

The short answer: principally to keep other traffic not going directly into or out of KORD separate.  A jet like that headed south east bound would probably get the MONKZ5 departure which holds them at 3000 ft until cleared to their filed altitude by ATC.  If it’s a busy day at the Chicago TRACON, I could see sending a jet north like that to climb above the Bravo, thence vectored direct to MONKZ and thence on to their filed route of flight.  That routing would give the crew a minimum of time in the class, bravo area, and simplify separation between arrivals and departures into O’Hare and those coming from satellite airports in the Chicago area.

Staying out of the Class Bravo is also very popular for VFR departures and arrivals, simply because it avoids the aggravation of dealing with ATC to transit that area.  The bravo is really a sterile area set up to deal with high speed IFR arrivals and departures of jet aircraft. Any other kinds of traffic are a second thought and the controlling TRACONs typically route lighter aircraft, either outside of the bravo, or with minimal invasion into the bravo. Quite often times, general aviation pilots will either fly under the bravo shelves, or avoid the place altogether, simply because they don’t like the hassle of dealing with ATC and doing so expedite their ability to traverse the area.